# Не получается добавить данные в базу данных sqlite

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite

Есть база данных:

```
package com.example.posts;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactDb";
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_MAIL = "mail";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID
                + " integer primary key," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_MAIL + " text" + ")");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

Есть активность:

```
package com.example.posts;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class NewEntry extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button btnAdd, btnRead, btnClear;
    EditText etName, etEmail;

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_entry);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
        btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();


        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnAdd:
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_NAME, name);
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_MAIL, email);

                database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);
                break;

            case R.id.btnRead:
                Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null, null, null, null, null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ID);
                    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME);
                    int emailIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_MAIL);
                    do {
                        Log.d("mLog", "ID = " + cursor.getInt(idIndex) +
                                ", name = " + cursor.getString(nameIndex) +
                                ", email = " + cursor.getString(emailIndex));
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                } else
                    Log.d("mLog","0 rows");

                cursor.close();
                break;

            case R.id.btnClear:
                database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null);
                break;
        }
        dbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

//данная активность не является главной активностью, то есть для перехода на неё необходимо нажать на кнопку на главной активности (не думаю, что это важно, но на всякий случай пишу)

Есть xml файл активности:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Read">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Манифест приложения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.posts">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".postsList"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".NewEntry" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

При вводе данных в активности и нажатии клавиши "сохранить" возникает ошибка:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table contacts has no column named name
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=to get a fh go mail=gfd do he hf
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(name,mail) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1546)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
        at com.example.posts.NewEntry.onClick(NewEntry.java:59)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вы отредактировали `onCreate`, но не перезапустили приложение? Попробуйте переустановить или увеличить версию базы `DATABASE_VERSION`.

```
DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Comment: День добрый. А почему вы на английском пишите?

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!